# Initial ordinals

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $cf(\lambda)$ be the least index $\xi$ such that a limit ordinal $\lambda$ is cofinal with the initial ordinal $\omega_\xi$. How can one prove that $cf(\omega_\Omega)\neq0$ where $\Omega=\omega_1$?

Comment: Your question is not very clear as written, especially the definition of $\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)$. What does it mean to be cofinal with the initial ordinal $\omega_\xi$?

Comment: Hint: try showing that $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_\alpha) = \operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ for any limit $\alpha$.

Comment: Nice hint! @Shervin

Comment: @Alessandro actually I use Kuratowski's terminology. He defines the cofinality of $a$ to $b$ as being the limit of an increasing $b$-sequence.

Comment: Yes, but your rephrasing is difficult to parse.

Comment: And it does not seem to be the standard definition.

Comment: According to your definition, is 0 the cofinality of $\omega$?

Comment: @Andres, I'll write the answer now. May be it gives clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the Axiom of Choice to prove this, so the proof you gave cannot be correct.

With $\mathsf{AC}$ every countable union of countable sets is countable. In particular, if $f:\omega\to\omega_1$ is increasing, then $\lim_{n\in\omega}f(n)=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}f(n)=\alpha$ is a countable union of countable sets (because each $f(n)<\omega_1$) and thus $\alpha$ is countable, which implies that $f$ is not cofinal in $\omega_1$. You could then combine this with the hint that was given in the comments above.

Without $\mathsf{AC}$ it is consistent that there exists a cofinal countable sequence in $\omega_1$. This means that it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ have the same cofinality.

Comment: it can be shown without $AC$ that $cf(\omega)=0$ and $cf(\Omega)=1$...

Comment: It cannot. In fact, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)=0$ for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$ simultaneously. See *[All uncountable cardinals can be singular](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760939)* by Gitik

Comment: ok, thanks, very interesting, though singularity means that cofinality is just strictly less than the index, it gives the answer.

Comment: Usually cofinality is defined as $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)$ being the least $\beta$ such that there is a cofinal sequence $\langle \alpha_\xi\mid \xi<\beta\rangle$. With this definition an ordinal is singular if $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)<\alpha$ and regular if $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)=\alpha$. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ it is provable that all successor cardinals are regular, but this uses choice by the result from the article above. Furthermore, it is not possible to prove the existence of a regular limit cardinal (also known as a weakly inaccessible).

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'm just trying to involve in studying set theory, that's why have a lot of fails)